# Performance of Select

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, filtering

I have a dataset of 3D coordinates with a length of about $ 4\times 10^6 $.

From this volume I am sequentially selecting coordinates along one axis and manipulating this subset.

My question: Can the `Select` function be replaced by something that is faster.

Here is the example code with the needed time for selection:

```
SeedRandom[1];

coordinates = RandomReal[10, {4000000, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.0989835, Null}

selectedCoordinates = Select[coordinates, #[[1]] > 6 && #[[1]] < 7 & ]; // AbsoluteTiming

{5.88215, Null}

Dimensions[selectedCoordinates]

{400416, 3}
```

Comment: `Pick[coordinates, 6 < # < 7 & /@ coordinates[[All, 1]]]` is almost twice as fast as `Select[..]`

Comment: You can compile your `Select`: `compiled = Compile[{{coords, _Integer, 2}},
  Select[coords, #[[1]] > 6 && #[[1]] < 7 &],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]` . Then `compiled[coordinates]` takes 0.2 secs on my machine.

Comment: `Cases[coordinates, {x_, y_, z_} /; x > 6 && y < 7]` Assuming that you want to get #[[1]]>6 &&#[[2]]<7. Otherwise the output would always by {}. No integer can be >6 and <7 at the same time ,-).

Comment: @RMMA: Thank you for your remark. I changed to `RandomReal`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
res1 = Select[coordinates, #[[1]] > 6 && #[[1]] < 7 &]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 6.997629

```
res2 = Select[coordinates, 6 < #[[1]] < 7 &]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 4.676356

```
res3 = Pick[coordinates, 6 < # < 7 & /@ coordinates[[All, 1]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 5.266651

```
res4 = Pick[coordinates, (1 - UnitStep[# - 7]) (1 - UnitStep[6 - #]) &@
      coordinates[[All, 1]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.353154

```
res6 = compiled[coordinates]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.667676

where

```
compiled = Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}}, Select[coords, #[[1]] > 6 && #[[1]] < 7 &]]`
```

is the method suggested in Leonid's comment (without the option `CompilationTarget -> "C").

```
Equal[res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, res6]
```

> True

Comment: Thank so much. The last solution is my case about 35 times faster than `Select`.

Comment: A fairer comparison would chain the inequalities for `Select` as well.  And it would be nice to include the comparison for a compiled selector.

Comment: @mrz, my pleasure, Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @Alan, I added the variant of `Select` you suggested. I don't have a c compiler installed, so i cannot include timings for the method suggested by Leonid. Without the `CompilationTarget->"C"` `compiled` is slower than `Pick`.

Comment: Something like `Pick[c,UnitStep[c-6,7-c],1]` is more compact, but is about 30 times slower than your `res4` formulation! The problem is with the multi-dimensional `UnitStep`. Something like `Pick[c, UnitStep[c - 6]*UnitStep[7 - c], 1]` seems as fast or slightly faster than the `res4` formulation.

Comment: @kennyColnago, i think we do need the more cumbersome `(1 - UnitStep[# - 7]) (1 - UnitStep[6 - #]) &` ; `Pick[c, UnitStep[c - 6]*UnitStep[7 - c], 1]` does not give the correct result.

Comment: Sorry, I was being brief to fit a comment, and used an imprecise notation qualified by "something like". Speaking more precisely, I should have said that `(1-UnitStep[#-7])(1-UnitStep[6-#])` is the same as the more direct `UnitStep[#-6]*UnitStep[7-#]`.

Answer (score 22):

Slightly faster than @kglr's solution is to use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
SeedRandom[1];
coordinates = RandomReal[10, {4000000, 3}];

r1 = Pick[
    coordinates,
    Unitize @ Clip[coordinates[[All,1]], {6, 7}, {0, 0}],
    1
];//RepeatedTiming

r2 = Pick[
    coordinates,
    (1-UnitStep[#-7]) (1-UnitStep[6-#])&@coordinates[[All,1]],
    1
];//RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.10, Null}
>
> {0.15, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ... I have to remenber `Clip` ... this function is extremely fast

Comment: Thanks. I learn about Pick, combined with Clip How wise!

Answer (score 4):

> My question: can the `Select` function be replaced by something that is faster.

Yes! Check out [the BoolEval package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/BoolEval).

```
SeedRandom[1];
coordinates = RandomReal[10, {4000000, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.118832, Null} *)

selectedCoordinates = 
   Select[coordinates, #[[1]] > 6 && #[[1]] < 7 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.08899, Null} *)
```

```
Needs["BoolEval`"]

selectedCoordinates2 = BoolPick[coordinates, 6 < coordinates[[All, 1]] < 7]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.145518, Null} *)

selectedCoordinates == selectedCoordinates2
(* True *)
```

Be sure to read the documentation of the package to see more usage examples and learn about caveats.

Comment: This is great! I just installed and tried it.