# Extracting elements in a list based on conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  {824, 1082, 1135, 1308, 1359, 1372, 1401, 1412, 1601, 
   1638, 1641, 1674, 1709, 1805, 1947, 2208}
```

I would like to extract a sublist according to certain defined conditions, such as extracting only values which lie in the range 1000-1500.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `Select[\[ScriptCapitalD], 1000 <= # <= 1500 &]` would do it. But there are many faster ways that already have answers somewhere here...

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158583/performance-of-select/158586#158586)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard Mathematica function for that kind of selection, is `Select`.

```
data = 
  {824, 1082, 1135, 1308, 1359, 1372, 1401, 1412, 1601, 1638, 1641, 1674, 1709, 
   1805, 1947, 2208};
Select[data, Between[#, {1000, 1500}] &]
```

> `{1082, 1135, 1308, 1359, 1372, 1401, 1412}`

#### Update

`Between` has an operator form, so

```
Select[data, Between[{1000, 1500}]]
```

will work and is nicer.

`Select` has its operator form, too, so one can also write

```
Select[Between[{1000, 1500}]] @ data
```

Comment: Can you explain what the operator & does in the argument of `Select`?

Comment: @Physkid When writing `&`, everything to the left of it becomes the body of a function. E.g with `plus = # + #2 &` then `plus[2, 3]` evaluates to `5`

Comment: @Physkid. Look up `Function` in the documentation.

Comment: @m_goldberg I like your  updated code-cleaner

Answer (score 4):

```
sdt = Select[dt, 1000 <= # <= 1500 &]

{1082, 1135, 1308, 1359, 1372, 1401, 1412}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cases[Clip[lst, {1000, 1500}, {0, 0}], Except[0]]
```

> {1082, 1135, 1308, 1359, 1372, 1401, 1412}

Alternatives, based on `Clip`:

```
lst // Pick[#, Clip[#, {1000, 1500}, {0, 0}] // Unitize, 1] &
Clip[lst, {1000, 1500}, {0, 0}] /. 0 -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you selection criteria is always a window (Between[{a,b}]), sorting the data and then doing a binary search may be more efficient.  See [Windowed binary search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/finding-all-elements-within-a-certain-range-in-a-sorted-list/2371#2371)