# Extract parameter values from a long table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long table with the form `{{a1,b1,c1}, ... , {an,bn,cn}}`; how do I extract the values of `a` and `b` corresponding to the maximum value of `c`?

Comment: `MaximalBy[list, Last]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also

```
TakeLargestBy[list, Last,1],
list[[Ordering[list[[All, -1]], -1][[1]]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

A comparison of the proposed methods (I stored the `Max` for the two last cases to avoid multiple computations).

```
SeedRandom[1]
tab[n_] := RandomReal[10, {n, 3}];

compare[n_] := With[{tab = tab[n]}, {
    RepeatedTiming@MaximalBy[tab, Last]
    , RepeatedTiming@TakeLargestBy[tab, Last, 1]
    , RepeatedTiming[tab[[Ordering[tab[[All, -1]], -1][[1]]]]]
    , RepeatedTiming[max = Max[tab[[All, 3]]]; Select[tab, #[[3]] == max &]]
    , RepeatedTiming[max = Max[tab[[All, 3]]]; Pick[tab, #[[3]] == max & /@ tab]]
    , RepeatedTiming[Pick[list, Unitize@Clip[
         list[[All, 3]], {Max[list[[All, 3]]], Max[list[[All, 3]]]}, {0,   0}], 1]]
    }[[All, 1]]]

res = Table[compare[Floor[10^n]], {n, 1, 6, 0.25}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose@res, DataRange -> {0, 10^6}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"MaximalBy", "TakeLargestBy", "Ordering", "Select", 
       "Pick", "Pick & Clip"}]
```

[image]

The `Ordering` method proposed by klgr is the fastest by far here. 
Second is the combination of `Pick` and `Clip` proposed by mrz (and earlier in [this post by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158597/18767)).

Comment: Please update you overview with the `Pick` and `Clip` solution (my lowest solution) which is slightly slower (on my computer) than `Ordering`.

Comment: @mrz Done. Don't hesitate to improve answers directly yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];

list = RandomReal[10, {10, 3}]

{{8.17389, 1.1142, 7.89526}, {1.87803, 2.41361, 0.657388}, 
 {5.42247, 2.31155, 3.96006}, {7.00474, 2.11826, 7.48657}, 
 {4.22851, 2.47495, 9.77172}, {8.25163, 9.25275, 5.78056}, 
 {2.9287, 2.08051, 5.80474}, {1.28821, 3.06427, 7.12012}, 
 {3.90582, 8.19967, 3.25351}, {5.9326, 5.18774, 1.69013}}

Select[list, #[[3]] == Max[list[[All, 3]]] &]

{{4.22851, 2.47495, 9.77172}}

Pick[list, #[[3]] == Max[list[[All, 3]]] & /@ list]

{{4.22851, 2.47495, 9.77172}}

Pick[
  list, 
  Unitize@Clip[
    list[[All, 3]], {Max[list[[All, 3]]], Max[list[[All, 3]]]}, {0, 0}
  ], 1
]

{{4.22851, 2.47495, 9.77172}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance is an issue, Pick gives a very fast answer:

```
Pick[list,list[[All,3]],Max[list[[All,3]]] ]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you !